# Why is timestamp part of every transaction input in hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

How can I prevent users from submitting a timestamp with their transaction?
When I create a transaction, the timestamp field is added to the transaction and can be inputted by the user.
While the timestamp on the transaction is populated if the client does not send it, the user can send in their own timestamp to back-date a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to enforce this in the client tier (prior to submitting the transaction using the Node.js or REST API).

This is an interesting requirement however. Can you elaborate more on the use case and what you are worried about?

Comment: Specifically, I want to know when the transaction processed and have an unalterable blockchain ledger record of that time.  Furthermore, I'd like my chaincode to execute logic based on that transaction timestamp and how it compares with timestamps stored within the asset database.

If a participant can backdate or forward date a transaction, the date field is meaningless, so could it be removed?

Comment: What time would you use for the transaction? How would it be computed? Welcome to the challenging world of temporal logic and distributed systems!